# Instead of attribute value, its displaying array of ids in view page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, database, ce-1.9.0.1, product-view

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/it-may-not-be-easy-but-it-will-be-worth-it-apple-iphone-4s-phone-case.html)

using **Ctrl + F**, please search for text "Product Lengthh"

It is **multi-select** attribute .you can see "**605**" , But we gave value : "mobile" . **I guess its displaying array of ids**.

Is there anything missing in database, as it not displaying the value present in backend. **attribute code : mobile_design**

```
app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/Attributes.phtml

    <?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <div class="fp1"><?php $Pro_name = $_product->getName();?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Specifications Of '."$Pro_name") ?></h2><br/><br/>


    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>  
            <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);

            /* hide abc */
            if($_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) == 'no') {
                continue;
            }           

            /* hide no abd*/
            if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && (trim((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) != ''))
            {
                if ($_data['code'] == 'gendernew'): 
                ?>              
                <tr><th colspan="3"><?php echo $this->__('') ?></th></tr>
        <th class = "tablehead" colspan="3" > GENERAL </th>
                <?php elseif ($_data['code'] == 'productweight'): ?>
                <tr><th class = "tablehead" id="prod_dim" colspan="3"><p style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% ! important; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px ! important;" class="Product_dim">Product Dimension</p><?php echo $this->__('PRODUCT DIMENSION') ?></th></tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <?php 
                if (/*stripos($_data['code'],',') === true &&*/ $_data['code'] == 'age')
                { ?>
                    <td class="data">
                        <?php
                            $_ageValues = $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
                            $count = 1;
                        ?>
                        <?php if(is_array($_ageValues)): foreach($_ageValues as $_ageValue): ?>
                         <?php if($count > 1) { echo ","; } ?>
                            <?php echo $_ageValue; ?>
                            <?php $count++; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; 
                        else: echo $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
                        endif; ?>
                    </td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getData($_data['code']), $_data['code']); ?></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>

            <!-- mobile -->

            <tr>
            <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mobile_design')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
            </tr>

            <!-- mobile -->


            <?php            
            }
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: plz show your file to check more reference.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: i used this code in attributes.phtml  [  <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mobile_design')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?> ], but its not working

Comment: is  mobile_design text type or select attribute?

Comment: its a multiselect attribute , attribute code : mobile_design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if($_product->getMobileDesign()) {
    foreach($_product->getAttributeText('mobile_design') as $type) {
        echo $type;
    }
}
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
 if($_product->getMobileDesign()) { 
$mobileDesigns = explode(",",$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mobile_design')->getFrontend()
->getValue($_product));

    foreach($mobileDesigns as $key => $value){
            echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```